# Как настроить в Linux компиляцию Qt на Qt4, а не Qt5?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt, компиляция, qmake

У меня ноутбук с установленной *Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3*.

Я установила библиотеку *Qt4* с помощью *apt-get install libqt4-dev*. После этого мои проекты на *Qt4* успешно собрались.
Затем  я установила *Qt Creator*, используя *Ubuntu Software Center* из меню на ноутбуке. При этом загрузился *Qt5*,  *qmake* начал формировать *Makefile* со ссылками на библиотеку *Qt5*, и проекты собираться перестали.

Как мне поменять настройки для *qmake*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Определите переменную окружения:

```
$ export QT_SELECT=qt4
$ qmake
```

или непосредственно только для одной команды:

```
$ QT_SELECT=qt4 qmake
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это сработало.